# Need an Idea how to deploy many images: One after the other

Tags: windows, images

I need an application that can backup and restore images from command line FROM windows.
My need is as follows:

1. Load an image of windows
2. Restart
3. Load a new image of windows
4. Restart
5. Load a new, 3rd image of windows
6. ....

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by loading an image?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a VM instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about operating system imaging, for applying and creating Windows images you generally use Windows PE and [ImageX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722145(WS.10).aspx). Also see the definition of  [Windows Imaging Format (WIM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format).

You could also, a bit more advanced, dabble with [Boot From VHD](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx) and simply change VHD files to boot from.

Comment: Thanks Oskar. That means that I need to install the full SDK to support WinPe from windows. I need a simple solution to change the opeating that will be loaded every boot. XP - BOOT - than VISTA- boot -Win7... Any idea how to perform that? Thanks!!!